# es6 class method unable to access local state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm pretty confident i'm doing this wrong, i'm unable to console.log `this.state.greeting` however if I reference this.state.greeting inside the return statement it works, i'm confused why it doesn't work within the class method

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      greeting: 'test'
    }
  }

  greeting () {
    console.log(this.state.greeting)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.greeting}>test</p>
    )
  }

}

export default Test
```

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two tricks to this one. You can either use the bind function in your constructor like so:

```
this.greeting = this.greeting.bind(this);
```

or if you have babel setup correctly with es6 and presets then you can do it a better way by using anonymous lambdas. Inside your `.babelrc` file it should look like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        "es2015",
        "stage-1"
    ]
}
```

and have the proper dependencies installed then you can use the es6 functions like this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

  }

  greeting = () => {
    console.log(this.state.greeting)
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.greeting}>test</p>
    );
  }

}

export default Test
```

Personally I love the second option. It doesn't bloat up your constructor, and the anonymous lambdas are nicer to type than function every time.

Comment: i love the sound of #2! Now I wish js-standard didnt complain about it lol

Comment: The official term for "anonymous lambda" is *arrow function*.

Comment: There is a third option as well if you're working in an environment without `stage-2` presets (which is what you need for the [es class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) you used up there). You can leave the `greeting` method as it is and change the `render` function to return this: `<p onClick={() => this.greeting()}>test</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind it. Here are two options:

```
class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      greeting: 'test'
    }
  }

  greeting () {
    console.log(this.state.greeting)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.greeting.bind(this)}>test</p>
    )
  }
}

// OR THIS

class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      greeting: 'test'
    }
    this.greeting = this.greeting.bind(this);
  }

  greeting () {
    console.log(this.state.greeting)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <p onClick={this.greeting}>test</p>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: your second solution doesnt work, it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

Comment: You can remove the `bind` call inside `render` here. Once the property is assigned in the constructor, you don't need to bind it again.

Comment: @alilland: that happens if you have a spelling error (i.e. `this.greeting` does not match the `greeting` function name). Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1887/

Comment: @RossAllen You are right. I copied pasted the first example to modify it and forgot to remove the bind